# Write a back reference in regular terms to determine the equality of two numbers

Tags: regex, bash, equality, backreference

Please tell, how it is possible to write a back reference in a regular expression to determine the equality of two numbers.

For example the person entered 24 and 24 appeared on the screen "ok", on the contrary when entered 24 and 23 person received "not ok"?

I tried as follows:

```
#!/bin/bash

read a
read b
if <("$a" == "$b")>.*<\1>
then
   echo ok
else
   echo not ok
fi
```

Comment: What is a backlink?

Comment: `if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ]` -- this is basic shell `if` syntax.

Comment: Backlinks to regular expressions, for example $egrep '<([A-Za-z]*)>.*</\1>'

Comment: i try in this way if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ], it's don't work

Comment: I think you mean back-references.

Comment: yes, you right)sorry

Comment: It definitely should work if the inputs are numbers. If they can be other strings you should use `=` instead of `-eq`.

Comment: displays an error: "test.sh: line 5:24: command not found"

Comment: You probably forgot the spaces around `[` and `]`

Comment: I've done some testing, it doesn't look like bash supports back-references in regular expressions. If it did, the way to do it would be `if [[ "$a-$b" =~ ^(.*)-\1$ ]]`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You only need a direct variable comparison:

```
#!/bin/bash

read a
read b
if [ "$a" -eq "$b" ];
then
   echo ok
else
   echo not ok
fi
```

[image]

Back-reference is for complex requirements like this:

https://javascript.info/regexp-backreferences

**Also regex is not used to compare different values**. It is used to compare the incoming value with a predefined, expected or desired pattern like this example in which the expected pattern is a mail and the incoming value could be any string

```
if [[ "$1" =~ ^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$ ]]
then
    echo "Email address $email is valid."
else
    echo "Email address $email is invalid."
fi
```